# Is using npm run preview for a svelte kit app after building it ok for production

Tags: javascript, hosting, sveltekit

I have a svelte kit app that uses the auto adapter. Is building it and then using npm run preview okay or is npm run preview just for testing out the build. I'd prefer self hosting if possible.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi @yeetsquad747. It seems I'm on the same path as you. Did you figure it out the answer?

Answer (score 0):

No, `vite preview`, [as stated here](https://vitejs.dev/guide/cli.html#vite-preview) is not for production use.

Instead, use some other approach to serve your application (will depend on application type/adapter).